# Recursive Function Composition in Scheme

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket

Below is an attempt I've made to create a procedure that returns the function composition given a list of functions in scheme.  I've reached an impasse; What I've written tried makes sense on paper but I don't see where I am going wrong, can anyone give some tips?

```
; (compose-all-rec fs) -> procedure 
; fs: listof procedure
; return the function composition of all functions in fs:
; if fs = (f0 f1 ... fN), the result is f0(f1(...(fN(x))...))
; implement this procedure recursively

(define compose-all-rec (lambda (fs)
     (if (empty? fs) empty
     (lambda (fs)
         (apply (first fs) (compose-all-rec (rest fs)))
     ))))

where ((compose-all-rec (list abs inc)) -2) should equal 1
```

Comment: Have you been introduced to a design recipe or other formal methodology for attacking these kinds of problems?  See: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/index.html  For example, you probably want to consider a few concrete test cases. Specifically, express expected output given some simple inputs.  You've gone straight into coding, and that's often a problematic approach for problems larger than one-liners.

Comment: Concrete example about the empty case: what should `(compose-all-rec (list))` be?  What do you expect `((compose-all-rect (list)) -2)` to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd try a different approach:

```
(define (compose-all-rec fs)
  (define (apply-all fs x)
    (if (empty? fs)
        x
        ((first fs) (apply-all (rest fs) x))))
  (λ (x) (apply-all fs x)))
```

Notice that a single `lambda` needs to be returned at the end, and it's inside that lambda (which captures the `x` parameter and the `fs` list) that happens the actual application of all the functions - using the `apply-all` helper procedure. Also notice that `(apply f x)` can be expressed more succinctly as `(f x)`.

If higher-order procedures are allowed, an even shorter solution can be expressed in terms of [`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) and a bit of syntactic sugar for returning a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function:

```
(define ((compose-all-rec fs) x)
  (foldr (λ (f a) (f a)) x fs))
```

Either way the proposed solutions work as expected:

```
((compose-all-rec (list abs inc)) -2)
=> 1
```

Comment: How can i change it to get fN(fN-1(...(f0(x))...)) ?

Comment: @user2075220 reverse the input list

Comment: Can i do this inside function?

Comment: @user2075220 why don't you try it? you can check it by yourself.

Comment: ok, thank you, i didnt know where to place reverse but i already got it

Answer (score 0):

Post check-mark, but what the heck:

```
(define (compose-all fns)
  (assert (not (null? fns)))
  (let ((fn (car fns)))
    (if (null? (cdr fns))
        fn
        (let ((fnr (compose-all (cdr fns))))
          (lambda (x) (fn (fnr x)))))))
```