# Using foldr with scheme

Tags: scheme

If I have a list of procedures. How can `foldr` be used to next the calls?
Like (new abs) => (new (abs x))
Note: `foldr` should return a procedure.

I have

```
 (define next 
    (lambda (ls)
      (foldr (lambda (x) x) (lambda (x) x) ls)))
```

But this is giving an error...

Comment: It'd be really useful if you show in the question a sample input with the expected output, otherwise it's not clear what you're asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first procedure passed to `foldr` must have two parameters, like this:

```
(define next
  (lambda (ls)
    (foldr (lambda (x a) <???>) ; It's not clear what do you want to do inside
           (lambda (x) x)       ; this is the identity function, what's it for?
           ls)))
```

Just to be clear:

- The first parameter to `foldr` is the procedure to be executed, and it receives two arguments: the first one is the current value in the list and the second the accumulated value so far
- The second parameter to `foldr` is the initial value, it's suspicious that you're passing the identity function, I bet that's not right
- The third parameter to `foldr` is the list to be processed

Comment: read my updated answer, it's the accumulated value. Also, are you sure this isn't the same as [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467201/recursive-function-composition-in-scheme)?

Comment: no, I dont want recursive. So why is the first argument of parameter 1 mean current value and the second one mean accumulated? Is this just how scheme works?

Comment: @omega That's how it is, read the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._foldr%29%29). And read my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14467705/201359) to the previous question, at the end there's a solution using `foldr`.

Answer (score 0):

The second arg to foldr should be the initial value for the result, typically an empty list.